# Visual Basic - Sending a Carriage Return to an E-Mail

Tags: vb.net, newline, tostring, stringbuilder, carriage-return

How can I send a string to an email with new lines (carriage returns) included?

The problem is that I am sending the string to an email, and the email strips out the carriage returns.

```
Dim myApp As New Process

    emailStringBuilder.Append("mailto:")

    emailStringBuilder.Append("&subject=" & tmpID & " - " & subject)

    emailStringBuilder.Append("&body= " & msgStringBuilder.ToString)

    myApp = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(emailStringBuilder.ToString)
```

Comment: Can you provide some code which demonstrates the issue? How are you adding new lines to the StringBuilder in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're adding to your StringBuilder without newlines as I've just tested it and it works fine for me.

```
Imports System.Text
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        sb.AppendLine("Line 1")
        sb.AppendLine("Line 2")
        sb.Append("Line 3" & vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("Line 4 without CRLF")
        sb.Append("Line 5")
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString)
    End Sub
End Module
```

For the above code I get the following output

> ```
> Line 1
> Line 2
> Line 3
> Line 4 without CRLFLine 5
> ```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Ok, so based on the new information (about the email) the above still holds true. If you add to a stringbuilder with `.Append` you will lose, or more correctly, not see newlines. Instead you must use `.AppendLine` which will add the all important CR and LF codes onto the end of your string.

However, I am a little confused how you are sending email. I've seen it done this way from a webpage before but never from vb.net. Sending an email this way will almost certainly force you to send an email without newlines!!

Can I suggest you look at the the following from Microsoft on how to send email from Visual Basic using the System.Web.Mail namespace. It's not hard and you'll get a lot more control over the email you send this way....

[Microsoft example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314201)

Comment: I added more information. I was wrong, the tostring was not stripped the new lines. It's when the string is sent to an email that the new lines are stripped.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone also looking for something that will work went sent to email, you want to do as in @CResults answer, but add `"%0A"` to each line.  This will get it through to most email clients.

Answer (score 0):

You could also achieve this by sending the email with the body in HTML format like so:

When the body of the message is in HTML format, add the `<br>` tags right in your String. `vbCrLf` and `StringBuilder` don't work if the body is in HTML format.

```
Dim mail As New MailMessage
mail.IsBodyHtml = True
mail.Body = "First Line<br>"
mail.Body += "Second Line<br>"
mail.Body += "Third Line"
```

If it is not in HTML format, you use `vbCrLf` or `vbNewLine`:

```
Dim mail As New MailMessage
mail.Body = "First Line" & vbCrLf
mail.Body += "Second Line" & vbNewLine
mail.Body += "Third Line"
```